# How do I design and simulate a system with the 80386?

Tags: simulation, microprocessor, proteus

I'm trying to design a computer system so as to learn about microprocessors and peripherals. A simulator that:

1. Allows various components connected at various parts of the 80386
2. Allows clock by clock simulation

would be preferable. I have simulated microprocessors (the 8086 to be specific) before with Proteus, and it was satisfying.
[image]

Proteus doesn't support 80386 and higher Intel microprocessors.

I asked this question on [Retrocomputing.SE](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/24894/how-do-i-best-simulate-a-80386). I have explored all the options recommended (qemu, dosbox-x, pcem). They are good emulators for running dos applications (that is, they run exe files) and they have a fixed internal architecture - ie, i cannot reconfigure the hardware. They are good for someone wanting to run old exe files and games - and I run a couple successfully. What I'm looking for is more first principles. I want to configure my hardware, so that I can place a programmable peripheral controller at a particular address.

What are other alternatives?

Comment: Minimum clock rate for the 386 is 12 MHz so, no cycle-by-cycle stepping. You need to find a CPU that can be run statically.

Comment: If memory serves, Intel switched to static logic with the 486, so if you wanted to run something slowly, that might be a better choice (but from a logical perspective, it's very similar to a 386).

Comment: @JerryCoffin are there software packages for the 80486 that you know of?

Comment: @DavidWarutumo: Do you mean software packages to run on a 486 (yes, certainly) or that simulate a 486 (not so sure). But what I (and I think Andy Aka) had in mind was running a CPU at extremely low clock speed, and (probably) stopping it ever few clock cycles (or so) so you could directly examine its internal state changes. Instead of simulating a 486, using an actual 486 in a way that gives (nearly) the same capability for examining its internals as a simulator would.